# Pandas dataframe applying logic to columns calculations

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, logic, date-arithmetic

Hi I have a huge dataframe with the following structure:

```
    ticker  calendar-date     last-update   Assets    Ebitda  .....
0   a       2001-06-30        2001-09-14    110       1000    .....
1   a       2001-09-30        2002-01-22    0         -8      .....
2   a       2001-09-30        2002-02-01    0         800     .....
3   a       2001-12-30        2002-03-06    120       0       .....
4   b       2001-06-30        2001-09-18    110       0       .....
5   b       2001-06-30        2001-09-27    110       30      .....
6   b       2001-09-30        2002-01-08    140       35      .....
7   b       2001-12-30        2002-03-08    120       40      .....
..
```

What I want is for each ticker: create new columns with % change in Assets and Ebitda from last calendar-date (t-1) and last calendar-date(t-2) for each row.

But here comes the problems:

1) As you can see calendar-date (by ticker) are not always uniques values since there can be more last-update for the same calendar-date but I always want the change since last calendar-date and not from last last-update.

2)there are rows with 0 values in that case I want to use the last observed value to calculate the %change. If I only had one stock that would be easy, I would just ffill the values, but since I have many tickers I cannot perform this operation safely since I could pad the value from ticker 'a' to ticker 'b' and that is not what I want

I guess this could be solved creating a function with if statements to handle data exceptions or maybe there is a good way to handle this inside pandas... maybe multi indexing?? the truth is that I have no idea on how to approach this task, anybody can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Step 1***
*`sort_values` to ensure proper ordering for later manipulation*

```
icols = ['ticker', 'calendar-date', 'last-update']
df.sort_values(icols, inplace=True)
```

***Step 2***
*`groupby` `'ticker'` and `replace` zeros and forward fill*

```
vcols = ['Assets', 'Ebitda']
temp = df.groupby('ticker')[vcols].apply(lambda x: x.replace(0, np.nan).ffill())
d1 = df.assign(**temp.to_dict('list'))
d1

  ticker calendar-date last-update  Assets  Ebitda
0      a    2001-06-30  2001-09-14   110.0  1000.0
1      a    2001-09-30  2002-01-22   110.0    -8.0
2      a    2001-09-30  2002-02-01   110.0   800.0
3      a    2001-12-30  2002-03-06   120.0   800.0
4      b    2001-06-30  2001-09-18   110.0     NaN
5      b    2001-06-30  2001-09-27   110.0    30.0
6      b    2001-09-30  2002-01-08   140.0    35.0
7      b    2001-12-30  2002-03-08   120.0    40.0
```

**NOTE:** The first `'Ebitda'` for `'b'` is `NaN` because there was nothing to forward fill from.

***Step 3***
*`groupby` `['ticker', 'calendar-date']` and grab the last column.  Because we sorted above, the last row will be the most recently updated row.*

```
d2 = d1.groupby(icols[:2])[vcols].last()
```

***Step 4***
*`groupby` again, this time just by `'ticker'` which is in the index of `d2`, and take the `pct_change`*

```
d3 = d2.groupby(level='ticker').pct_change()
```

***Step 5***
*`join` back with `df`*

```
df.join(d3, on=icols[:2], rsuffix='_pct')

  ticker calendar-date last-update  Assets  Ebitda  Assets_pct  Ebitda_pct
0      a    2001-06-30  2001-09-14     110    1000         NaN         NaN
1      a    2001-09-30  2002-01-22       0      -8    0.000000   -0.200000
2      a    2001-09-30  2002-02-01       0     800    0.000000   -0.200000
3      a    2001-12-30  2002-03-06     120       0    0.090909    0.000000
4      b    2001-06-30  2001-09-18     110       0         NaN         NaN
5      b    2001-06-30  2001-09-27     110      30         NaN         NaN
6      b    2001-09-30  2002-01-08     140      35    0.272727    0.166667
7      b    2001-12-30  2002-03-08     120      40   -0.142857    0.142857
```

Comment: @StephenRauch a while, I mix it up.  Still not settled on a consistent format.

Comment: Well this is absolutely great, thanks!                                                          The only problem is that I still miss 2 pieces on which probably I was not clear enough in the explanation:     1)I would like to have all the % changes of last-Update rows since last calendar-date change ( in this specific case the only difference from my desiderata is that at index 1 Ebitda_pct should be -0.08 and not -0.2000                    2) I also would like to add other 2 columns with assets_pct and Ebitda_pct since t-2 (in this case for example pct_change between Assets at index 3 and 0)